# Problem getting data from Arduino pro mini

Tags: programming, arduino-pro-mini

I am currently working on a drone project using multiwii.
I m using mpu6050 as gyro and accelerometer sensor with i2c protocol. I was able to read data coming from mpu6050 while using Arduino Uno through multiwii but can't get it work with Arduino pro mini. I was able to get data with pro mini while using i2c scanner and mpu6050 test codes available on web but can't see any data from sensor on multiwii platform though it shows that Arduino is connected. I tried using pull up resistors and try with another pro mini but with no luck. One note is that because I will be using this with a 1s lipo battery ,I bootloaded both pro mini with 8mhz internal oscillator at 3.3v and even tried using external oscillator 8mhz but with no luck (I actually modified both of them cause 3.3v Mini's are not available in my country). I am using Arduino Uno without ic to program the pro mini board and its having no problem while programing or while reading data on serial monitor but only with multiwii. I tried multiwii with my Uno and nano and both worked just fine so right now I m wondering if on board programmer effects this but I have seen some people using pro mini with multiwii
My connections are not lose at all cause I soldered them directly to the Uno board.